# Random paths from one point to another going through all the cells of a square grid

Tags: graphs, randomized-algorithms

I am looking for a very specific algorithm, so I think it doesn't exist yet. I would be satisfied if anyone was able to give me some hints to develop it.

My problem is about a square grid of size `n x n`, where `n` is an odd natural number ≥3. For instance, it can be a 5 by 5 grid:

```
.---.---.---.---.---.
|   |   |   |   |   |
.---.---.---.---.---.
|   |   |   |   |   |
.---.---.---.---.---.
|   |   |   |   |   |
.---.---.---.---.---.
|   |   |   |   |   |
.---.---.---.---.---.
|   |   |   |   |   |
.---.---.---.---.---.
```

The middle cell of the first column and the middle cell of the last column must be found:

```
.---.---.---.---.---.
|   |   |   |   |   |
.---.---.---.---.---.
|   |   |   |   |   |
.---.---.---.---.---.
| ● |   |   |   | ● |
.---.---.---.---.---.
|   |   |   |   |   |
.---.---.---.---.---.
|   |   |   |   |   |
.---.---.---.---.---.
```

Then, and this is the hardest part of the algorithm, I want to get a path from the left-most point to the right-most one, that goes through every cell of the grid.

For example, this is one possibility:

```
  > > v   > > > > v
  ^   v   ^       v
  ^   v   ^   v < <
  ^   v   ^   v    
  ●   v   ^   v   ●
      v   ^   v   ^
  v < <   ^   v   ^
  v       ^   v   ^
  > > > > ^   > > ^
```

and this is another:

```
  > > > > v   > > v
  ^       v   ^   v
  < < <   v   ^   v
      ^   v   ^   v
  ● > ^   v   ^   ●
          v   ^    
  v < < < <   ^ < <
  v               ^
  > > > > > > > > ^
```

This implies directly some obviousnesses. Let `a` be the number of up displacements, `b` down, `c` left and `d` right, we can know that:

- `a + b + c + d = n^2 - 1`
- `a = b`
- `d - c = n - 1`

I also want to randomize the creation of this path, and the best would be a uniform distribution amongst all the possibilities (I don't know their number but I am almost sure it increases as `n` increases).

I think it can be solved thanks to graph theory since my grid can be considered as an unoriented graph where the vertices are the cells and where two adjacent cells are linked with an edge. The problem is now equivalent to making a non-redundant graph traversal, but I have no idea where to begin.

I hope my question was clear enough, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

A depth-first search with backtracking algorithm would work. This algorithm tries all 4 directions and is capable of finding all possible paths.

In order to find a random path, you could traverse the 4 directions in a random order at each step, and stop the first time the path fills all the cells AND ends in the target cell.

Start with a grid filled with 0. The algorithm would set cells to a value greater than 0, counting the steps, beginning with 1 at the starting cell.

The algorithm stops and backtracks any time it walls itself in, like the Snake game. In this case, it resets the cell to 0.

But eventually it will find a solution, if one exists. Otherwise, all possible paths are traversed.

The number of paths grows very quickly, so in practice, this algorithm would take an enormous amount of time to complete, even for smaller grids of say size 9 or 11. Optimizations would be important, for example detecting loops that cut off empty cells and make them unreachable. This is considerably more complex to implement, but is essential for a decent runtime in practice.

Here's an example implementation in C#:

```
void Main()
{
    // define a 5x5 grid and start and end squares
    int Rows = 5, Cols = 5, StartRow = 2, StartCol = 0, EndRow = 2, EndCol = 4;

    // Grid starts with all zeros
    var Grid = new int[Rows,Cols]();

    bool CreatePath(int r, int c, int number)
    {
        // if out of bounds or a collision, don't move this way
        if (r < 0 || r >= Rows || c < 0 || c >= Cols || Grid[r, c] > 0)
            return false;

        // take the next step
        Grid[r, c] = number;

        // if all cells are filled, check whether path ends at the correct place
        if (number == Rows * Cols)
            return (r == EndRow && c == EndCol);

        number++;

        // recursively search in all 4 directions in a random order
        // note that the "return true" after each is an indicator
        // that a path has been found, and leaves the path in Grid.

        foreach (int direction in RandomPermutation([UP, LEFT, RIGHT, DOWN]))
        {
            switch (direction)
            {
                case UP:
                    if (CreatePath(r - 1, c, number)) return true;
                    break;
                case LEFT:
                    if (CreatePath(r, c - 1, number)) return true;
                    break;
                case RIGHT:
                    if (CreatePath(r, c + 1, number)) return true;
                    break;
                case DOWN:
                    if (CreatePath(r + 1, c, number)) return true;
                    break;
            }
        }

        // all searches have returned: backtrack out of this cell
        Grid[r, c] = 0;
        return false;
    }

    // start the search
    if (CreatePath(StartRow, StartCol, 1))
    {
        // print Grid
    }
    else
    {
        // No path exists
    }
}
```

This will find just one path meeting your requirements, but it can easily be modified so that instead of stopping it continues the traversal, so that it enumerates all possible unique paths.

Comment: We're not a coding site. We discourage answers that consist of just a large block of code.  We'd prefer to see ideas, concise pseudocode, explanation of how/why your approach works, proofs/justifications of correctness, etc.  Can you [edit] your answer to add any of that?